# Discord py: Why are 2 conditions met when only 1 must be met?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been finishing adapting my old bot to the Cogs system, however suddenly I have found a strange problem that I cannot understand why it is happening

The code is very simple, I generate a variable between 1-4 and depending on the number that has been generated it must respond with a different image

The problem is that, however, 2 conditions are met when only 1 single condition should be met, And I don't understand why it could be happening-

I have tried to use elif, a unique variable for each command, etc. But the problem persists

```
import discord
import random
from discord.ext import commands

class sfw(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self._last_member = None

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def kiss(self,ctx, member:discord.Member):
        author = self.bot.get_user(ctx.author.id)
        embed = discord.Embed()
        image = random.randint(1,4)
        if image == 1:
            embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/UcTK9YF.gif")
        if image == 2:
            embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/jX2iVsz.gif")
        if image == 3:
            embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/Jhgzh9B.gif")
        if image == 4:
            embed.set_image(url="https://i.imgur.com/KAlaAJS.gif")
        await ctx.send(f"{author.mention} give kiss to {member.mention}",embed=embed )
```

However, it always returns 2 answers, instead of just 1.

I have thought about setting the range from 0 to 4, but the problem still persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first remove all 'variables' from your problem.

Dissect it, take simple steps, remove async, libraries and add them carefully, one thing a time and test each time, until you detect who is generating the two calls and generating the unexpected call.

Probably you are invoking the member function twice.

Comment: This is more a comment than an answer

Comment: I just discovered that the problem is in another module, for some reason the other module is making it take a double input. The problem is finding what generates that input

Answer (score 0):

The problem was generated in another cog file, which took a double input due to a bad indentation of the await command ```self.bot.process_commands (message)´´´

For some reason this caused any message to be heard 2 times by the bot. I hope that if someone else has my problem in the future this answer will help